# REACT Plotly - TypeError: createPlotlyComponent is not a function

Tags: reactjs, plotly-dash, plotly.js

When moving to the latest plotly their example no longer works

The plotly-react readme points to this codepen (in the Loading from a  tag section) :
https://codepen.io/rsreusser/pen/qPgwwJ?editors=1010

Increasing the version of react-plotly.js from "1.0.2" gives error "latest"
TypeError: createPlotlyComponent is not a function. (In 'createPlotlyComponent(Plotly)', 'createPlotlyComponent' is an instance of Object)

Would love to know how to solve this... (tried many things - I'm not a js expert)

html:
`<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-plotly.js@latest/dist/create-plotly-component.js"></script>`

js:
`const Plot = createPlotlyComponent(Plotly);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In https://unpkg.com/react-plotly.js@latest/dist/create-plotly-component.js you can see a line `exports["default"] = plotComponentFactory;`

I guess the factory isn't set up properly.

`const Plot = createPlotlyComponent.default(Plotly)` works.

You could also do:

```
createPlotlyComponent = createPlotlyComponent.default
const Plot = createPlotlyComponent(Plotly)
```